# Discrete normal subgroup of a connected linear lie group

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, normal-subgroups

It is known that a discrete normal subgroup $N$ of the connected group $G$ is contained in the center of $G$. But we also know that if a group is discrete then its Lie algebra is $\{0\}$, and we know that if $G$ is connected then $\exp(\mathfrak{g})$ generates $G$, where $\mathfrak{g}$ is its Lie algebra.

So consider the Lie algebra of the subgroup $N$: this has to be $\{0\}$, and so $N$ has to be $\{1\}$, which means $N$ must be in the center. However this seems false somehow. Where exactly am I going wrong?

Comment: This is not because the Lie algebra of $N$ is 0 that $N=1$...

Comment: @AlexL I realize that, I'm wondering where I'm going wrong...

Comment: The Lie algebra of a discrete subgroup $N$ is $\{0\}$. A connected Lie group is generated by the exponentials of its Lie algebra. The only explanation is that a discrete Lie group is not necessarily connected. Hence not necessarily generated by those exponentials. Wait! A discrete topological space is connected if and only if it is a singleton,

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I see...N is not connected, even though G is. This is the flaw

Answer (score 2):

*From the comments above.*

---

A discrete topological space is connected if and only if it is a singleton. In particular, the hypothesis that $G$ is connected does not imply that the discrete normal subgroup $N$ is also connected. Hence, it is not true that $N = \langle \exp(X) : X \in \mathfrak{n} \rangle$.

Thus, $\mathfrak{n} = \{0\}$ does not imply that $N = \{e\}$.